# How to transform nested vectors into a map of vectors?

Tags: clojure

Given I have the following form:

```
(def data-points [[1483249740 "ONE"]
                  [1483249680 "TWO"]
                  [1483249620 "THREE"]
                  [1483249560 "FOUR"]])
```

How can I transform this data into this?

```
{:data  [1483249740 1483249680 1483249620 1483249560] 
 :value ["ONE" "TWO" "THREE" "FOUR"]}
```

I would also like to know how to approach similar problems.
What is your way to break this down and what functions do I need to know to transform any data.

I'm new to clojure and haven't found a satisfying solution for this.
Thank you

Comment: The step is to realize that name of the operation: Transpose. There are a few SO questions about how to do it. Ans: `(apply mapv vector data-points)`. The rest is easy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i would use this:

```
(zipmap [:data :value] (apply map vector data-points))

;;=> {:data [1483249740 1483249680 1483249620 1483249560], 
;;    :value ["ONE" "TWO" "THREE" "FOUR"]}
```

it uses a single pass over the data collections, but more concise than the reduction, yet shouldn't differ in terms of performance

the snippet `(apply map vector data)` is quite an idiomatic way to transpose matrix in clojure (in your case it is what you need, since it turns columns into rows)

```
user> (apply map vector [[:a 1] [:b 2] [:c 3]])
;;=> ([:a :b :c] [1 2 3])
```

Comment: Wow, thank you. 
I was not aware that map can take multiple collections and zips them together. This makes the transformation so simple.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably write this as a reduction. This approach only requires a single pass over 'data-points' which may be preferable.

```
(reduce
  (fn [m [data value]]
    (-> m
        (update :data conj data)
        (update :values conj value)))
  {:data [] :values []}
  data-points)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another representation which can be both efficient and easier to work with:

```
(def data-points-map
  (into {} data-points))
```

Then you can do

```
(get data-points-map 1483249740)
```

to get "ONE". Otherwise you would need to

```
(aget (:value m) (.indexOf (:data m) 1483249740))
```

to achieve the same result.

Finally you can

```
{:data (keys data-points-map)
 :value (values data-points-map)}
```

to get the "weird" representation in the original question.

Comment: This approach would backfire if the keys (e.g. `1483249680`) aren't unique, and the original order of the key/value pairs won't be preserved if there are more than a handful of entries.

Comment: Both valid points. I assumed the data is coming from some sort of database query where key uniqueness is guaranteed and item order is irrelevant. Thanks for pointing out the assumptions inherent in my code. A very useful skill.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an obtusely functional way to do it

```
(->> data-points
     (mapv (partial mapv vector))
     (mapv (partial zipmap [:data :value]))
     (reduce (partial merge-with into)))
```

As a function:

```
(def format-data-points
  (comp (partial reduce (partial merge-with into))
        (partial mapv (partial zipmap [:data :value]))
        (partial mapv (partial mapv vector))))

(format-data-points data-points)
```

(I wouldn't recommend doing either of these actually, just presenting this for fun)

Comment: Pointfree Clojure, nice :)